# MySQL cursor using last cursor to update all column

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to loop through City and practice column in aqi table inside aqi_db database.
I did exact same thing on other database in my computer and it worked fine but when I created new procedure to use on different table, database it is not working properly.

This is what my table looks like:

```
ID  Country City    Aqi   lat      lng              time            practice
1   Canada  Acton   63  51.4925 -0.257252   2019-07-24 14:00:00     33
2   Canada  Alameda 46  37.7936 -122.263    2019-07-24 07:00:00     33
3   Canada  Altona  46  53.5557 9.94306     2019-07-24 17:00:00     33
5   Canada  Amherst 31  42.8864 -78.8784    2019-07-24 10:00:00     33
6   Canada  Athens  32  33.9458 -83.3722    2019-07-24 08:00:00     33
7   Canada  Massa   54  30.2583 -97.7203    2018-05-03 16:00:00     33
```

for each iteration I am trying to concatenate City and practice and update current practice row. desired result looks like:

```
ID  Country City    Aqi   lat      lng              time            practice
1   Canada  Acton   63  51.4925 -0.257252   2019-07-24 14:00:00     Acton33
2   Canada  Alameda 46  37.7936 -122.263    2019-07-24 07:00:00     Alameda33
3   Canada  Altona  46  53.5557 9.94306     2019-07-24 17:00:00     Altona33
5   Canada  Amherst 31  42.8864 -78.8784    2019-07-24 10:00:00     Amherst33
6   Canada  Athens  32  33.9458 -83.3722    2019-07-24 08:00:00     Athens33
7   Canada  Massa   54  30.2583 -97.7203    2018-05-03 16:00:00     Massa33
```

but instead it is returning

```
ID  Country City    Aqi   lat      lng              time            practice
1   Canada  Acton   63  51.4925 -0.257252   2019-07-24 14:00:00     Massa33
2   Canada  Alameda 46  37.7936 -122.263    2019-07-24 07:00:00     Massa33
3   Canada  Altona  46  53.5557 9.94306     2019-07-24 17:00:00     Massa33
5   Canada  Amherst 31  42.8864 -78.8784    2019-07-24 10:00:00     Massa33
6   Canada  Athens  32  33.9458 -83.3722    2019-07-24 08:00:00     Massa33
7   Canada  Massa   54  30.2583 -97.7203    2018-05-03 16:00:00     Massa33
```

I've check my code several times, I do not understand why this is the case. my code:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_aqi()
begin
    DECLARE v_city varchar(75);
    DECLARE v_practice varchar(10);
    DECLARE v_finished integer default 0;
    DECLARE c1 CURSOR for select City, practice from aqi;
    DECLARE continue handler for NOT FOUND set v_finished = 1;
    open c1;
    my_loop: LOOP
        FETCH c1 into v_city, v_practice;
        if v_finished = 1 then
            leave my_loop;
        end if;
        UPDATE aqi SET practice = concat(v_city, v_practice);
        END LOOP my_loop;
    close c1;
end $$
call update_aqi();
```

Further goal: Instead of updating each row in practice column with concatenate(city, practice) I want to trigger python function that receive city as a parameter and return value which will get updated in practice column.
NOTE: python function will call an api.
Any tips on how to go about it?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Oops forgot lol. Will do!

Comment: You need to add a WHERE to your UPDATE statement, without it you are updating the entire table. `UPDATE aqi SET practice = concat(v_city, v_practice) WHERE id = <the id of the row you are currently editing>;`

Comment: Or better yet you can update the entire table with one query `UPDATE aqi SET practice = CONCAT(city, practice);`

Comment: Oh thank you! I don't know why it worked before. Do you have any comment for my further goal (stated in question)?

Comment: Well it seems like a reasonable thing to do, is there anything in particular about the function you want to create that you need help with?

Comment: I've already created a function in python but I am trying to figure out a way to call that python function within MySQL. My goal is to call api every hour and update database Aqi and time column with returned data.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately my advise is don't do that. I would call the python script every hour and use that to update the table

Comment: Okay, one more question what happens when my program need to query database that is getting updated?

Comment: If you do one row at a time then there will not be a problem. This kind of thing only really becomes an issue when you update all rows of a really large table at once or change the schema of a particularly large table

Comment: I am planning on writing a script that gets column as list and iterate them and updated it with returned value, even though it is updating one by on, program will run for a while..